# Cycle2 - Adding Metadata to image tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle2

I am using the latest version of the jQuery plugin Cycle2.

I am creating `img` tags programmatically with jQuery. I wish to assign some metadata about the image to the image, which I do like so:

```
var info =  {title: "A Cool image", credit:"Martin Wesface"};
$("#container").append('<img src="myImg.jpg"/>').data(info);
```

Then I am hooking into the `cycle-update-view` event handler, and attempting to get my data out like so:

```
$("#imgContainer").on("cycle-update-view", function(event, optionHash, slideOptionsHash, slide) {
    $("#imgContainer> .title").html($(slide).data("title"));
    $("#imgContainer> .time").html($(slide).data("credit"));
});
```

The problem is that the `$(slide).data()` doesn't contain my data anymore. I think it's being overwritten by `Cycle2`.

Is there some other place to put my metadata, or a different approach I should take?

Answer (score 0):

The answer here is simple. I was attaching my data attributes to the `parent` of the image, rather than the image itself.

The fixed code looks like this:

```
var info =  {title: "A Cool image", credit:"Martin Wesface"};
$('<img src="myImg.jpg"/>').data(info).appendTo("#container");
```